# grouping data in postgres with titles of categories extracted from the data

Tags: postgresql

In my database I have data that has no category grouping such as A - Z

e.g

```
Data   | column grouping
----------------------
Water  |  W
-----------------
Win    |  W
-----------------
Jet    |  J
-------------------
Jeles  |  J
```

I only have

```
Data
---------
Water
--------
Win
-----------
Jet 
---------
Jeles
```

Is it possible in the database to select the starting char of each record in each row then group the data with titles as beginning chars of the group such that the result is as shown

for those starting with A,B,W ... etc

result

```
**W**
Water
Win
**J**
Jet 
Jeles
```

Kindly advise or can this only be done by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data get all the distinct first chars of the column `"Data"` and then use UNION ALL for the table:

```
select t."Data"
from (
  select distinct concat('**', left("Data", 1), '**') "Data"
  from tablename
  union all
  select "Data"
  from tablename
) t 
order by trim(both '*' from t."Data")
```

I assume there are not any leading or trailing characters `'*'` in the column `"Data"`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sFWhTeVQpPzEREJu33fFYX/4).
Results:

```
| Data  |
| ----- |
| **J** |
| Jeles |
| Jet   |
| **W** |
| Water |
| Win   |
```

Comment: Thank you so much @forpas, that is what I wanted